# TFS Eclipse Plugin detects wrong files edited

Tags: eclipse, tfs, eclipse-plugin, team-explorer-everywhere, tfvc

Eclipse TFS Plugin says that a lot of files includes images (.png, vs..) have been edited although I have made no change to them when I open the "detect local changes" tab.
I understand the files in bin/ folder are supposed to have been edited but I don't understand the other files as I mentioned above to be seen as edited by TFS Eclipse Plugin. Is there any idea of its reason or a solution for it?

Comment: Are you using Local or Server workspaces?

Comment: I don't really know, how can I detect if I use Local or Server workspace? (Note : The source code exists in both my computer and TFS server.)

Comment: I found it from "Manage Workspace" tab. It is Server workspace!

Comment: I changed all files to be Read & Write also, this may cause this problem for Server workspace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're using a Server workspace, TFS treats any file that does not have the Readonly bit set as changed. That's how Server workspaces work.

If you want TFS to reflect the contents of the file you will need to "Undo unchanged", which TFS will automatically do when you check in (TFS never creates two revisions when both have the exact same contents).

Or switch to a Local workspace, in which case TFS will store a copy of your file in a hidden folder, so that it always knows what your workspace version looked like when TFS served it to you.

---

TFS 2010 does not support local workspaces. Also note that [TFS 2010 general support ends July 2015](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle?p1=15011), it's really recommended you upgrade to TFS 2013u4 now or TFS 2015 as soon as it releases.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I can not select the location property as "Local" while creating the workspace, it is disabled and only choice is "Server". And When I click "Undo unchanged", it says that "All pending changes have been modified since being checked out" and nothing happens.

Comment: Can we change the workspace to treat all files that have the Readonly bit set as changed?

Comment: With server workspaces files are always checked out when the readonly bit is not set. There is no way around that.

Comment: What version of tfs are you connecting to? 2010 by any chance?